# When I use k8s kubeadm init, I get and Invalid value error

Tags: kubernetes

When I type, `kubeadm init` into the terminal, I get and Invalid Value error:

```
root@kevin-Lenovo-Y430P:/home/kevin# kubeadm init 
[kubeadm] WARNING: kubeadm is in alpha, please do not use it for production clusters.
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.5.4
discovery: Invalid value: null: exactly one discovery strategy can be provided
root@kevin-Lenovo-Y430P:/home/kevin#
```

When I use `kubeadm init -h  find` the output is:

```
--discovery discovery  The discovery method kubeadm will use for connecting nodes to the master (default unknown)
```

So what are the discovery methods that I can choose?

Comment: Can you post the output of: kubeadm version

Comment: I have solved the problem by myself。The reason of the this problem is that I forget disable SElinux 。

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been solved by disabling SELinux.